# Cookie not set until a second refresh

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I have a form on page 1:

```html
<form method="post" action="request-form">
    <input
        type="text"
        id="amzQry"
        name="item"
        placeholder="What do you need?"
        autocomplete="on"
    />
    <input
        id="autocomplete"
        name="destination"
        placeholder="where? (e.g. Buenos Aires)"
        onfocus="geolocate()"
        type="text"
        required=""
        aria-required="true"
        autocomplete="off"
    />
    <button type="submit" value="">
        Submit
    </button>
</form>
```

I want this information to be held in a persistent way so that even if a user subsequently logs in (to joomla in this case) the cookie data is persistent and can be called. That is why i have used cookies rather than sessions in this case. Correct me if this is not the right way of doing this.

I have some code to set and retrieve the cookie on page 2:

```php
<?php
    $itemcookie = $_POST['item'];
    $detsinationcookie = $_POST['destination'];

    setcookie("itemcookie", $itemcookie, strtotime('+30 days'));
    setcookie("destinationcookie", $detsinationcookie, strtotime('+30 days'));
?>
```

But the cookie data is not appearing on the second page when it loads after form submit. If I refresh the second page the data appears in the right places, i.e. where I have called it with e.g.

```php
<?php
    echo $_COOKIE["itemcookie"];
?>
```

How to get the cookie data available immediately on page 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

If you check the [manual](http://php.net/setcookie):

```
Once the cookies have been set, they can be accessed on the next page load with the $_COOKIE or $HTTP_COOKIE_VARS arrays.
                                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This means your cookies will not be available on the page / script where you set them.

You could use another variable to show the value though, for example like:

```
$itemcookie_value = isset($_POST['item']) ? $_POST['item'] : $_COOKIE["itemcookie"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have some output before you call setcookie()
If you have some output (even one single space character) BEFORE session_start(), setcookie() or, say, header(), the browser will not recognize the cookie and they won't be available right after the script starts.

Comment: This is in a component file in Joomla. I guess there is quite a lot of output before the component file. So how to get the data into cookie before submit I guess, javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You can.

All you have to do is set the cookie with a AJAX request that way the cookie is set while you are still on the page then when you refresh the page ONE time the cookie will be available to you.